# Loss function forcing orthogonality for the encoding of an autoencoder (NPCA)

Tags: keras, autoencoder, loss, orthogonal

I have implemented an autoencoder that should realize a non-linear version of a principal component analysis. In- and Output of the model is a the same dataset with n features and I am interested in the encoding which has dimension d<n. To generalize the principal component analysis I would like to have an encoding that consists of d almost linearly independent vectors, but if I use the loss function "mse" I get e.g. for d=2 two vectors which look almost the same.

Theoretically I could use a loss function including a penalty term for vector that are similar and far from independent. But that would mean to have a loss function that uses the information of the whole batch not just a single sample and not from the output but from an intermediate layer.

Since I am working with Keras: Can anyone give me hint or a reference how I can approach this problem in Keras?

Comment: Did you solve the problem, Anne ?

Comment: This [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-the-right-autoencoder-tune-and-optimize-using-pca-principles-part-ii-24b9cca69bd6) solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not impose orthogonality on the features, but weights.